# Как можно изменить код?

Tags: c++, инспекция-кода

Задание:Структура с именем TRAIN поля:
-название пункта назначения;
-номер поезда;
-время отправления
Способ обработки 
–
вывод на дисплей 
результата сравнения: верно ли
,что названия пунктов назначения совпадают у двух поездов
Как можно изменить код?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, system("pause") or input loop */
struct TRAIN {
    char *name;
    int number;
    float time;
};
void inTrain(TRAIN *train) {
    cout <<"Введите данные: "<<endl;
    cout <<"Пункт назначения: "<<endl;
    train->name = new char[25];
    cin  >>train->name;
    cout <<"Номер поезда: "; cin >>train->number;
    cout <<"Время отправлени: "; cin >>train->time;

}
void outTrain(TRAIN *train) {
    cout <<"Пункт назначения: "<<train->name<<endl<<"Номер поезда: "<<train->number<<endl<<"Время отправления: "<<train->time<<endl;
}
int main() {
    TRAIN tr1,tr2,*train1, *train2;
    train1 = &tr1;
    train2 = &tr2;
    int num;
    while (1) {
        cout << "Выберите действие: " <<endl<< "1 - Ввод данный" <<endl<< "2 - Вывод данных" <<endl<< "3 - Обработка" <<endl<< "4 - Выход" << endl; 
        cin >> num;
        switch(num) {
            case 1: inTrain(train1);
                    inTrain(train2);
                    break;
            case 2: outTrain(train1);
                    outTrain(train2);
                    break;
            case 3: if (tr1.name == tr2.name) cout <<"True"<<endl;
                    else cout<<"False"<<endl;
                break;
            case 4: return 0;
            }

        }
        return 0;

    }
```

Comment: Я уже писала - замените тип на string. Для с-строк сравнение делается только с помощью функций.

Comment: А также функции inTrain и outTrain сделать членами класса и убрать параметры, которые будут неявно доступны через this.

Comment: Я не первый раз вижу этот код и все он его не улучшает, несмотря на ответы.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/724816/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%BD%D0%B0-c?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

```
tr1.name == tr2.name
```

Ну не сравнивают так строки... Вы проверяете, не один ли и тот же адрес у `name` в `tr1` и `tr2`...

```
if (strcmp(tr1.name,tr2.name) == 0) { ... }
```

Вот это - сравнение **строк**, а не адресов.

Answer (score 1):

1. Или сравнивать так

   ```
   case 3: if (strcmp(tr1.name,tr2.name)==0)
   ```
2. или, что лучше, заменить тип на string.

Comment: Вполне является.